# How to create shared formula in Excel via Automation

Tags: excel, automation, formula, shared

I just write a VC Automation program by importing the type library of Excel 2003 and then using the classes. How to create a shared formula via the automation classes. I cannot find a property/method in MS document related to create shared formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can use Range.copy for creating a shared formula.

And the parameter of this method is the target range.

Please look at the below sample:

Excel.Worksheet objWorkSheet= (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

```
        Excel.Range oResizeRange;
        objWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "1.33";
        objWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "1.565";
        objWorkSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "1";
        objWorkSheet.Cells[4, 5] = "1";
        objWorkSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "1";
        objWorkSheet.Cells[6, 5] = "1";
        oResizeRange = objWorkSheet.get_Range("E8", "E8").get_Resize(Missing.Value, 1);
        oResizeRange.Formula = "=SUM(E2:E6)";
        objWorkSheet.Range["F1"].Formula = "=E1*10";
        objWorkSheet.Range["F1"].Copy(objWorkSheet.get_Range(oWS.Range["F2"], objWorkSheet.Range["F8"]));
```

This is a C# sample and I found the same method in VC .